# Browser freezes when connecting to SQL Server in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I wrote a simple program to check for a name in the database. Everything seems to be correct but every time I try to connect to the database my browser freezes. No errors were displayed or caught. I have confirmed that the database and server in the connection string are correct (I have connected to the same server before in another program. For a different database and it worked fine) Please can someone help me with a solution.

```
SqlConnection conn;
SqlCommand comm;
SqlDataReader reader;

string connectionString = "Server=SHADOW;Database=Store;Integrated Security=True";

conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
comm = new SqlCommand(
            "SELECT UserID, Name, Password FROM Users" +
            " WHERE Name=@Name", conn);
comm.Parameters.Add("@Name", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar);
comm.Parameters["@Name"].Value = txtUserName.Text;

try
{
    conn.Open();
    reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.Read())
    {
        //if (txtUserName.Text == reader["Name"].ToString())
        //txtUserName.Text = "Successful";
     }

     reader.Close();
 }
 catch (Exception err)
 {
     txtUserName.Text = err.Message;
 }
 finally
 { 
     conn.Close();
 }
```

Comment: It seems very unlikely that a database connection problem on the server side will make your "browser freeze". Can you provide a bit more detail about exactly how the "browser freezes"?

Comment: when I click the submit button which run the code above that particular page in the browser freezes. Any other thing I click does not work

Comment: The "freeze" is probably the browser waiting for a response from the server. Willing to bet if you wait 100 seconds (default timeout setting defined in web.config or IIS) you get an actual exception message. Check the connection details to the sql server, and check the firewall

Comment: Think you need to be a bit more specific about 'freeze'. (Sorry to be pedantic). If the UI has become unresponsive, and the browser software has 'crashed', then the problem isn't on your server. So this is a massive curve ball. If you mean it's taking a while to load, then I recommend you debug and find out what line it's freezing on.

Comment: You could make an async request using AJAX. So if the select needs a lot of time to complete the browser won’t “freez” and you can display a wait dialog.

Comment: I tried using other browsers(chrome and firefox) and it worked fine. The problems seems to be from Internet Explorer.